# 2 queries on the same model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder

i wanted to fetch all the rows from `Course` table whose `userId` is `$userId` . And from that list, i wanted to select the row which has the `id` field value as same as the inputted value `$id`. I tried the below one. It  returns `null`. Any solutions?

```
$course=Course::where('userId',$userId)->pluck('id');
$data=$course->where('id',$id)->first();
dd($data);
```

Comment: why are you not using multi where in first query `$course=Course::where('userId',$userId)->where('id, $id)`

Comment: @Yogendra that solves this.thanks

Comment: Or better use it in One Query `$course = Course::where([ ['userId','=',$userId], ['id,'=', $id] ])->first();`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using 'pluck' - that's just pulls out the specified column for matching records, and nothing else. Your **$course** collection (which is what's returned from your first line) is therefore just a collection containing IDs and nothing else.

You can chain multiple 'where' clauses together :

```
$course = Course::where('userID', $userID)->where('id', $id)->first();
dd($course);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shorthand, which lets you pass in both search parameters in the where method.

```
$course = Course::where([
  'id' => $id,
  'userID' => $userID
])->first();
```